# WHILE loop shows a different output than FOR loop

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

As far as I know the difference between `for` loop and `while` loop looks like this:

**for:**

fist initialization takes place then conditional expression is checked and if it results in `TRUE` then only statement part gets executed this loop is continuous till conditional expression results `FALSE`.

**While:**

conditional expression is checked first and if result `TRUE` then statement part gets executed otherwise not, this loop is continuous till conditional expression results `FALSE`.

---

Today I wrote an Algorithm which check if a `string` has duplicates, and if so to print only those which aren't:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    const char *str = "Mississippi";
    char tmp[15] = {0};
    size_t i=0,j=0,k=1;
    int found=0;

    tmp[0] = str[0];

    printf("Before = %s\n",str);
    while(str[i] != '\0'){
        for(j=0;tmp[j] != '\0';j++){
            if(tmp[j] == str[i]){
                found++;
            }
        }

        if(found==0){
            tmp[k]=str[i];
            k++;
        }

        found=0;
        i++;
    }

    tmp[strlen(tmp)] = '\0';
    printf("After  = %s\n",tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before = Mississippi
After  = Misp
```

Now watch what happens if replace the `for` loop:

```
for(j=0;tmp[j] != '\0';j++){
    if(tmp[j] == str[i]){
        found++;
    }
}
```

With a `while loop:

```
while(tmp[j] != '\0'){
    if(tmp[j] == str[i]){
        found++;
    }
    j++;
}
```

I get:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
    const char *str = "Mississippi";
    char tmp[15] = {0};
    size_t i=0,j=0,k=1;
    int found=0;

    tmp[0] = str[0];

    printf("Before = %s\n",str);
    while(str[i] != '\0'){
        while(tmp[j] != '\0'){
            if(tmp[j] == str[i]){
                found++;
            }
            j++;
        }

        if(found==0){
            tmp[k]=str[i];
            k++;
        }

        found=0;
        i++;
    }

    tmp[strlen(tmp)] = '\0';
    printf("After  = %s\n",tmp);
    return 0;
}
```

But the output is not as expected:

```
Before = Mississippi
After  = Misp
```

But:

```
Before = Mississippi
After  = Misisipi
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: TLDR; please provide a short and sweet [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which illustrates the problem. Don't post code that works.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry about that, removed the part with the example.

Comment: Down Voter Please explain, why? Is there any chance to see who down voted me?

Comment: that flagged me as my comment was above - but it wasn't my downvote.

Comment: I really need to know, what was wrong with this question. ThisiIs not right, what's happens here.

Comment: Perhaps it was for the reason in my critical first comment - some people here are very quick to downvote. Have a +1 on me. But I think you are whistling into the wind: the downvoter is unlikely to revisit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's missing is that the `for` loop is initializing `j` to 0 when it first enters.

Although `j` is initialized to 0 when it declared, the `while` loop is called within another `while` loop, so it doesn't get reinitialized each time.

Add the initialization:

```
    j=0;
    while(tmp[j] != '\0'){
        if(tmp[j] == str[i]){
            found++;
        }
        j++;
    }
```

And you get:

```
Before = Mississippi
After  = Misp
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the while loop does not initialize `j=0` at every iteration of the outermost while loop!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `while` loop doesn't initialize `j` to `0`.

Remove the initialization of `j` to `0` and add

```
j = 0;
```

in front of your nested `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You never reset j to 0 with the while loop.

This bit:

```
for(j=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

[for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

> ```
> for ( init-statement(optional) ; condition(optional) ;
>       iteration_expression(optional) )
>   statement
> ```
>
> The above syntax produces code equivalent to:
>
> ```
> {
>   init_statement 
>   while ( condition ) { 
>     statement 
>     iteration_expression ; 
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Except that
>
> 1. Names declared by the init-statement (if init-statement is a declaration) and names declared by condition (if condition is a
>      declaration) are in the same scope (which is also the scope of
>      statement).
> 2. `continue` in the statement will execute iteration_expression
> 3. Empty condition is equivalent to `while(true)`